# Dismissing a numeric keyboard

Tags: swift

A noob question here:  I have read a lot about dismissing the keyboard from objects like labels or event when one taps the RETURN key or other areas of the screen.  However, is there code to dismiss a keyboard from within a BUTTON?  I tried various ways of ResignFirstResponder at the end of the code in my BUTTON but to no success.

Any help that can be shed would be appreciated.  Please remember I a new to all this so I please be as specific as possible.

Thank you

Comment: What platform? iOS, macOS, tvOS?

Comment: dismiss a keyboard from within a BUTTON? What do you mean by that? Your keyboard is in a button or u want to dismiss the keyboard when that button is pressed?

Comment: Sorry - Platform  is iOS. In my program, I have defined a BUTTON called "btnCalculate" which does a calculation based on user input from two text fields.  When the user presses the "btnCalculate" button, I want to do the calculation, dismiss the keyboard, and display the results.  All is working except being able to dismiss the keyboard with code within the "btnCalculate" function. - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send `endEditing(_:)` to the text field that is the first responder, or to any superview of it, to make it resign first responder and dismiss the keyboard. The window is a view, and is a superview of all your other views, and is easy to get a reference to:

```
@IBAction func calculateButtonWasTapped(sender: AnyObject?) {
    view.window?.endEditing(true)

    // perform calculation here
}
```

Comment: This worked!  Thank you both for the solution and also for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just say that the text field is called `theTextField`, and when pressed the `UIButton` runs an `@IBAction` called `buttonTapped()`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var theTextField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        theTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you skunkmb.  This also works however I would have to "resignFirstResponder" for all the textfields since any of them could be the firstResponder.  With the "end.Editing(true)", I only have one entry to make.  However, thanks for your solution.  By experimenting with it, I now have a better understanding of this topic.